# How can I merge duplicate accounts if support doesn't help me?

Tags: support, status-completed, merge-accounts

I want to merge my accounts.

I sent an email to Support Team three times. First time a month ago. And nothing...

How can I do this? Who can help me?

Thank you.

**UPDATE:** 15 min after this question - Support helped me. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry about that. Merging is a [multistep process](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) that requires some manual steps on your part and on ours. I got your initial request and had you put "merge delete" and "merge keep" in your accounts. For some reason, we didn't hear back from you until Friday. Then we have to read your response and act upon it manually. Since we don't work weekends typically, tickets tend to pile up on Mondays. And blah, blah, blah.

Needless to say, none of us are very happy about the current situation and one of our current focuses is eliminating or streamlining some of the manual steps. Yours was a fairly simple case, actually. Sometimes it takes several exchanges to verify that both accounts are owned by the same person. It's too late for your merge, but we are working toward improving the process for future merges.