# Why is my new account on an SE site only sort of attached?

Tags: support, profile-page, login, user-accounts

I started [a new biology SE account](https://biology.stackexchange.com/users/73101/jim) and used my Google information to log in. Now, I haven't used any SE site in perhaps two years, so I wouldn't be surprised if my [old account](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/6385/scalia) from a deactivated email wasn't attached to my Google profile anymore. However, my old gravatar loaded in as an option for profile picture.

[image: See that radish?]

My hope that I can recover my old rep is partially restored. Is there something I can do to fully attach my two accounts?

I'd like to specify it appears both accounts are tied to the same Google profile, but not the same e-mail. Supposedly any accounts I create on other Stack Exchange sites should be attached, but they aren't.

Comment: The process to merge accounts is the same no matter the details: you have to contact Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Jim, see also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231119/282094